# Implementing shadow to Floating Action Button

Tags: android, xml

I wanted to implement shadow to `FloatingActionButton`. I saw some solution saying to add `app:borderWidth="0dp"`, but that didn't work for me.
I couldn't find any solution to add shadow to the button.

This is my `FloatingActionButton`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFab"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

How can I implement shadow to this `FloatingActionButton`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: width should be wrap content

Comment: I tried giving width wrap_content, it is not working.

Comment: add this attribute `app:borderWidth="0dp"`

Comment: I have already added that, you can see that in the question but still I am not getting shadow.

Answer (score 0):

For shadow, you just need to the required `app:elevation="10dp"` I've set **10dp** you can check the shadow effect will increase.

Comment: No still shadow is not coming